# Distribution of the dot product of a multivariate gaussian random variable and a fixed vector

Tags: random-variable, linear-algebra, multivariate-normal-distribution

If $a$ is a multivariate normal random variable, and $x$ is a plain old vector (of the same shape as $a$), then the inner product $x \cdot a$ is a random variable. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765672/distribution-of-inner-product-of-normal-random-variable-by-a-vector) post on math exchange suggests that the product will have a univariate normal distribution, but I haven't been able to frame the problem in a way that leads me to calculating $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Edit: For posterity, the answer to this question was made much clearer to me by understanding [a proof of the affine property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dot product is equivalent to linear combination in your situation. $x\cdot a = x_1a_1 + x_2a_2+...+x_ka_k$

Suppose $a \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, then scale $x\cdot a$ follows univariate normal distribution: $x\cdot a\sim N(x\cdot \mu, x\Sigma x') $

Comment: Perhaps it is worth emphasizing that $x\cdot \mu$ is a scalar too, as is $x\Sigma x^\prime$ and thus $x\cdot a \sim N(\ldots)$ is referring to a univariate normal distribution

Comment: Thanks. This is axactly what I asked for :) What would be the general approach for answering this for some other multivariate distribution?

Comment: Let $Y$ be random vector with mean $\mu$ and variance matrix $\Sigma$, $AY$ has the mean vector $A\mu$ and variance matrix $A\Sigma A'$ is true always. But the distribution of $AY$ depends on the distribution of $Y$.