# Distribution of the dot product of a multivariate Laplace random variable and a fixed vector

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-variable, multivariate-normal-distribution, linear-algebra, laplace-distribution

This question is basically a follow-up: [Distribution of the dot product of a multivariate gaussian random variable and a fixed vector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375068/distribution-of-the-dot-product-of-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-and-a)

But instead of a multivariate Gaussian random variable, what about a multivariate Laplace random variable?

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) it seems that there is no easy way to deduce the distribution of a sum of laplace variables. It is likely some overly complicated function. I really hope you don't need an analytic expression, because it is either very hard or impossible

Comment: Yes I hoped for something analytic. Is the property that I look for called ''stability''? Or is ''affine transformations'' different.

Comment: Dot product is a linear combination. That means you need to find the distribution of a sum of laplace random variables, where each variable is multiplied by a different constant. So if you can figure out what happens to laplace random variable when it gets multiplied by a constant, and then what happens when you add two or more results like that together, you can eventually get at an answer. But I suggest that you give up, it is likely not worth it. If you can afford to, estimate the distribution numerically instead

Comment: I see. Do you know if there is distributions other than the Gaussian distribution that satisfies this property?

Comment: Saddlepoint approximations could work for this problem!

Comment: I think gaussian is the only distribution with such nice properties, for everything else you have to do work. One other idea to consider is that by central limit theorem a sum of a bunch of similarly-distributed r.v. very quickly starts looking like a gaussian (times N) with some mean and variance. If your dot product has sufficiently many terms, maybe it is possible to make use of it. However, if it is not quite there, finding by how much your sum deviates from a gaussian is again hard. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution for uniform

Comment: Make note however that Irwin-Hall only works for sum of standard uniform variables, but for dot product you need to scale each random variable by a different factor. I don't know if there are extensions that can account for that, but, as you see, the PDF is already quite ugly involving a sum, and it is only going to get worse

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I did not know about this, but sounds very useful, probably better than pure numerics

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers! I'd love to upvote, but I think it is not possible to do so on comments.